# Abstract machine or algorithm for line solving a Nonogram

Tags: ds.algorithms

I am currently working on a little project where I would like to write an efficient solver for three-dimensional Nonograms.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonogram

So I wanted to ask whether anybody of you know a good way on how to solve a line in a normal 2D Nonogram. The problem is NP-complete btw so finding a robust algorithm that always does it will be quite hard ;-)

But does anybody of you have an idea? It doesn't need to solve everything possible but should do basic checks on a line and see if it can fill out something.

Would be  great if anybody could give me tips on how I could achieve this... thanks!

Comment: I didn't get it...Are you seeking an approximation algorithm? Or, you don't care if it takes exponential time; you just want it solved?

Comment: right, I would like to solve it... and even if it takes exponential time... but I would also be fine with a method that doesn't detect everything possible but most cases where it can fill (parts) of a line...

Comment: You could check out this [theory of a nonogram solver](http://www.comp.lancs.ac.uk/~ss/nonogram/theory.html) page. I typed "nonogram solver" into Google and it was one of the first hits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

... or **if you just want to have fun** you can simply grab a lot of useful tips from other (powerful) Nonogram solvers; you can start from here:

http://webpbn.com/pbnsolve.html which will *teleport* :-) you to:

http://webpbn.com/survey/ and ...

http://www.comp.lancs.ac.uk/~ss/nonogram/ ...

http://www.comp.lancs.ac.uk/~ss/nonogram/list-solvers

You can find detail descriptions of single-line / multi-line solving techniques and descriptions of more complex strategies.

When switching to 3D Nonograms single-line and multi-line strategies are still valid (apply 2D multi-line strategies on each *section* of your 3D puzzle); but if the 3D puzzle is difficult (or random), an iterated loop with those strategies ends up with many *unknown* pixels and to proceed you must apply specific 3D strategies.

If your question is more *TCS oriented*  then there are plenty of references in some public downloadable articles: http://www.google.it/search?as_q=nonogram+np&as_filetype=pdf

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to reduce it to a SAT problem (which should be trivial for this game, notice that each cell is a variable and that the constraints will form the clauses) and then use a modern SAT solver. You could search for a SAT solver which is good in solving satisfiable instances fast (this will always be satisfiable and will always have exactly one answer). You could check the [SAT competition website](http://www.satcompetition.org/) for a fast solver.

Unless I totally misunderstood something, this should be enough for a fast problem solver.